# Putting dropdown option in input bar

Tags: css, autocomplete

So, I have a search bar and drop down menu:

```
<input placeholder="Name Search" name="sp_name" id="sp_name" class="btn-block"/>    
<input type="submit" id="sp_search_submit" class="btn" value="Search">
```

and

```
<select name="sp_name" id="sp_name" class="input-small btn-block">                              
    <option value="" type="text"><?php _e('All Names', 'my_site') ?></option>
    <option value="Steve" <?php selected('Steve', isset($_GET['sp_name']) ? $_GET['sp_name'] : ''); ?>>Steve</option>
    <option value="Mike" <?php selected('Mike', isset($_GET['sp_name']) ? $_GET['sp_name'] : ''); ?>>Mike</option>
    <option value="Sean" <?php selected('Sean', isset($_GET['sp_name']) ? $_GET['sp_name'] : ''); ?>>Sean</option>
</select>
```

Now, both the "Name Search" bar and dropdown menu have same id of `"sp_name"`.

In other words, you will get results either by inputting the name or selecting one of the options.

However these are two separate parts and it takes up spaces as shown below in the image.

I am trying to add the dropdown menu as a part of the input search bar as shown below.

[image]

So, you can either choose to type the name or select from one of the choices from one single bar.

I tried to put the `<input>` as one of the `<select>` option, but it didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"both the "Name Search" bar and dropdown menu"*. That's not valid HTML, regardless of the version. Any ID ___must___ be an __unique__ identifier. They can, however, have the same name, but that can lead to interesting side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This;

You can use following reference mention at below:

[Jquery Autocomplete Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

[Kendo Autocomplete Combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index)

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="Soptions" style="visibility: hidden">                              
  <option value="Steve" <?php selected('Steve', isset($_GET['sp_name']) ? $_GET['sp_name'] : ''); ?>Steve</option>
  <option value="Mike" <?php selected('Mike', isset($_GET['sp_name']) ? $_GET['sp_name'] : ''); ?>Mike</option>
  <option value="Sean" <?php selected('Sean', isset($_GET['sp_name']) ? $_GET['sp_name'] : ''); ?>Sean</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
var texts = [];
var sel = document.getElementById('Soptions');
for (var i=0, n=sel.options.length;i<n;i++) {
  if (sel.options[i].text) texts.push(sel.options[i].text);
}
</script>
        <div id="example">
            <div>
                <h4>Choose User Name:</h4>
                <input id="User" style="width: 25%;" />
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#User").kendoAutoComplete({
                        dataSource: texts,
                        filter: "startswith",
                        placeholder: "Select Name...",
                        separator: " "
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like the jQuery autocomplete, but I was just wondering if you know what the browser compatibility is like.

Comment: @steveKim Mozilla firefox is more compatibility. You can use google chrome too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5 [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) instead.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?